Matplotlib 3.9.2 not rendering TeX text or formulae
A very simple Python code like the one below:
from numpy import cos, pi, linspace
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, rc

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = linspace(-pi, pi, 200)

    rc('font', **{'family':'serif', 'serif':'Computer Modern Roman'})
    rc('text', usetex=True)

    font = {'family': 'serif',
            'color' : 'darkblue',
            'weight': 'bold',
            'size'  :   18,
           }

    plt.figure(1,figsize=(9, 8))

    plt.plot(x, cos(x), 'b-', markersize=3, linewidth=2)
    plt.title(r'$f(x) = cos(x)$', fontdict=font)
    plt.xlabel('$x$', fontsize=18)
    plt.ylabel('$f(x) = cos(x)$', fontsize=18)

    plt.show()


was working fine until a couple of weeks ago. But since yesterday I'm getting the following error message:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/cm/cmr10.tfm'

Yet I have MikTex, and the font cmr10.tfm is on:
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts\tfm\public\cm

and
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts\

is in the PATH. What might have happened? I have Windows 11, Python 3.10.8, Matplotlib 3.9.2, MiKTeX 24.4.
